# wymeditor - formatting headings in stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, wysiwyg, wymeditor

**I'm trying to use within wymeditor the same styles that are on my website.** Unfortunately this editor is barely documented, so I don't really know how to do it.

The [documentation](http://trac.wymeditor.org/trac/wiki/0.5/Customization.html) implies something like you can use a stylesheet where you define everything in some form, and it will be parsed and used in the editor. I could do this, but only with the classes (second box on the right panel).  The documentation gives an example, but only for the classes, not for the containers. There's a link to a full stylesheet, but it's a dead link, and the [stylesheet](http://files.wymeditor.org/wymeditor-1.0.0b2/examples/styles.css) used in the examples only define classes and no containers.

**So how would I make for example a red h1 in the editor? Or at least in the preview.**

I would be really glad if someone linked or gave a full example of a stylesheet where containers like h1 and p are also formatted and used in editor. If this is not possible, what are other ways to do it?

---

**EDIT:**

I could inject CSS to the iframe with postInit:

```
postInit: function(wym) {
    var $head = $(wym._box).find('iframe').contents().find("head");
    $head.append($("<link/>", { 
        rel: "stylesheet",
        href: costumIframeCss,
        type: "text/css"
     }));
}
```

Now the only thing that I need is to do a similar thing to the preview dialog. Maybe with the **postInitDialog(wym,wdw)**. I don't really know how yet. The big problem there is that I need to differentiate the preview dialog from the other dialogs.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**:

I saw that you have access to dialog window as `wdw`, when using `postInitDialog`. Thats cool. The way you did it (looking at your update) the same you you can for Diaolog too

Look at the following image. I debugged the Preview dialog, as it opens.
Look at line no. `41`

[image: Inspecting the Preview]

Following what you did to the editor, the same can be done to the Preview
At line no. `41`, you can get the `head` and append the style in the same way

```
var $head = $(wdw.document.body);
$head.append($("<link/>", { 
    rel: "stylesheet",
    href: customPreviewCss, // CSS for Preview Dialog
    type: "text/css"
}));
```

**Initial Answer**:

As I understand, you want the styles to take effect while you are editing. Ideally, for making an `h1` red in color while editing (or any such customization), you have only the following options:

- Use the proper classes, as explained by the documentation - The very
  purpose of an editor is this. Customization should be done on top of
  what is there
- **Edit the default stylesheet** which you have linked or
  is loaded **when editor is active** (you can check that using inspect
  element) This is explained below

I see that when you are using the editor, it loads in an `iframe`. An `iframe` has **its own styles**. Now, inspect the element. In your case its an `h1`, but I am using the `p` tag from the example

[image: Inspecting the Editor itself]

See that it loads the styles **from another file** - `wymiframe.css`, line no. `51` for a `p` tag

So if you want to change or add your own styles, go to that file. (If you hover own it, you get the file path, or right click and *open in new tab* and check from the address bar)
**Add or edit** the style of `h1` there. Done.
Also, you can go to the respective `html` file in the `wymeditor/iframe/default` folder. Add your custom `link` to your own css file. In this file, do all desired customization :)

Hope it helped !

Comment: So does this mean that the stylesheet parameter is only for classes? And is that why I can't define containers within it?

Comment: These are acceptable last resort solutions, but none of them are as dynamic as I'd like. I was hoping for something like: $('textarea').wymeditor(iframeCss: 'style.css'); but based on what you said I got a pretty good idea on using the iframeHtml customization option to create just this.

Comment: @SinistraD, for your **1st comment**, If I understand it correctly, stylesheet will have definitions for `DOM` tags. To be able to define containers within it, the `wymeditor` guys have to enable it. That makes me to answer your **2nd comment** - The `wymeditor` people have to enable feature so that you can use `$('textarea').wymeditor(iframeCss: 'style.css');`. As of now, in the absence of this feature enabled by `wymeditor`, I think my answer should work. If so, and if you accept the answer, I will be **delighted**

Comment: @SinistraD, Updated my answer looking at your update to question

Comment: I could make it work. You didn't answer the full question, only pieces of it (necessary pieces), so I won't mark it as solution, but I'll give you the bounty, because you deserve it. Thank you, for helping.

Comment: @SinistraD, Thanks. Did you check my updated answer? I assume that now, you only wanted to add custom styles to Preview Dialog, which you already did for the editor. So I debugged the Popup of `default` editor from the site. I found that you can do the same way in Popup also. When you create the `wymeditor`, you have `postInitDialog` in which their is access to `wdm`. Styles can be added there explained in my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

As you see those are just the samples. You can't use that as an editor online. You 'll have to download that and try using it.

```
http://files.wymeditor.org/wymeditor-0.5/examples/
```

The above shows the list of examples. In that you have tried with the first link.

To download it go to this link.

```
http://www.wymeditor.org/download/
```

Select the recent stable versions for less flaws.

Hope this helps.

And as you have asked it works very well in the preview, when submitting nothing is getting reflected.

To achieve that in the preview, click on the HTML icon that is present at the second last position.

Write your own code, clicking on preview gets your result in a new pop up window.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. I know I need to download it and I also know how to install it, my question was how do I use my own heading styles within the editor? And/or how do I inject my own CSS to the pop-up preview?